# Create multi-COMMAND execute_process

Tags: cmake

According to documentation `execute_process` can accept more than one command and AFAIR they gonna be executed in parallel, so running multiple `execute_process` is less than desirable. Each command should be created in runtime by iterating over list. The problem is `execute_process` could not accept string which contains the `COMMAND` token and the command with arguments like below and `execute_process` does not support chaining command by using `&&`:

```
set(commands)
foreach (Node ${NodeList})
    string(REGEX MATCHALL "[A-Za-z0-9_\\.]+" NodeDefinition "${Node}")
    list(GET NodeDefinition 1 IP)
    list(APPEND commands "COMMAND ssh -tt user@${IP} \"${command}\"")
endforeach ()
list(JOIN commands "\n" exec_commands)
message(STATUS "Commands: ${exec_commands}")
execute_process(${commands})
```

It gives

> execute_process given unknown argument "COMMAND ssh -tt user@127.0.0.1 "ls /bin""

Is there a way to workaround the problem?

EDIT001: Looks like the `execute_process` would work if I do it this way:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${command1}
                COMMAND ${command2}
                ...
                COMMAND ${commandn}
                )
```

Looks like `macro` will solve this problem

EDIT002: Well, it didnt

EDIT003: According to @Tsyvarev comment, I dont have to create stringy command, just append all to list, as well, skip double quoting the command. The working code looks like

```
foreach (Node ${NodeList})
    string(REGEX MATCHALL "[A-Za-z0-9_\\.]+" NodeDefinition "${Node}")

    list(GET NodeDefinition 0 Name)
    list(GET NodeDefinition 1 IP)
    string(SUBSTRING ${Name} 0 8 starts_with)

    if (starts_with STREQUAL "ch_node_")
        list(APPEND commands COMMAND ssh -tt user@${IP} ${command})
    endif ()
endforeach ()
execute_process(${commands})
```

Comment: If you want to pass a **list**, do **not** enclose it into **double quotes** (in the line `list(APPEND commands "...")`). See e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297840/cmake-cannot-run-shell-command.

Comment: I think this is not what I need. I need each COMMAND as entry in a list, if I wouldnt put it double quotes I will get each token as an entry in a list. I will update question to clarify stuff

Comment: Still don't understand the problem... You have included milti-COMMAND signature of `execute_process`; note: there is no double quotes around the `COMMAND` keyword. And this is what I meant in my previous comment: you need not to add double quotes around `COMMAND` and its subsequent arguments. But you may still have `${command}` argument quoted.

Comment: The line `execute_process(COMMAND ssh -tt user@127.0.0.1 "ls /bin")` would run `ls /bin` on the target machine. Note, this line **does not use variables** at all. But if this command does what you **eventually** want to achieve, then `execute_process` is no longer your issue: What you need is to fill `commands` variable with a required content.

Comment: I think I dont get you... Do you mean I have to add double quotes around each `COMMAND`? Like this list(APPEND commands "\"COMMAND ssh -tt user@${IP} \"${command}\"\"")

Comment: In opposite, you need to **not** add double quotes around `COMMAND`.

Comment: Oh, I see... And it supposed to work? Just pass a list as argument to the `execute_process`? Is `execute_process` should be able to "understand" how to cope with it?

Comment: Yes, just try that.

Comment: Why not put `execute_process()` in the `foreach()` block so it runs a separate process per iteration?

Comment: @squareskittles it will execute sequentially

Comment: Ahh ok, misread your question. Thanks

Comment: @Tsyvarev Boom! Works like a charm! Thanks (again) for your help!

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg If you found a solution to the issue, please post it as an *answer* to your question and mark as accepted so others can know which solution worked.

Comment: @Tsyvarev would you like to convert your comment to answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing multiple commands to `execute_process`, these commands are separated **solely** by the `COMMAND` **keyword**, there is **no** need to "group" commands with **double quotes**.

Following `execute_process` will run 3 commands:

```
execute_process(COMMAND echo abc
                COMMAND mkdir foo
                COMMAND ssh -tt user@127.0.0.1 ls /bin)
```

So, when forming commands in a variable, double quotes are not needed either:

```
# Incorrect
list(APPEND commands "COMMAND ssh -tt user@${IP} \"${command}\"")
# Correct
list(APPEND commands COMMAND ssh -tt user@${IP} ${command})
```

(Quotes around the command passed to `ssh` for execute on the target machine are not needed either, `ssh` automatically treats every argument, followed the executable, as arguments to that executable.)

---

Note that commands in `execute_process` are not executed strictly in order, but piped: output of the first `COMMAND` is piped into the second one, output of the second one is piped into the third one, and so on.